# bash ignores what I type while "apt-get" is running

Tags: apt, bash

I am encountering this problem:

I type `sudo apt-get install <package>`, and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  `apt-get` starts resolving dependencies and downloading/installing packages.  While it is running, I want to enter another command in the same terminal, so I type it (let's say `echo done`).

The problem is, I type `echo done` and <kbd>Enter</kbd>, but when `apt-get` finishes, the `echo done` is not executed.  The shell comes back to me with a prompt, and there is nothing in its input buffer.  So, `bash` seems to ignore my input while `apt-get` is running.  This "ignoring" doesn't seem to happen with any other command.

I would like to figure out why this is happening, and if I can change the behaviour somehow.

Comment: I recommend [reporting this as a bug](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs).

Comment: FWIW, I tried it right after doing sudo apt-get update, and it worked as expected.

Comment: @MartyFried, just to be sure: once `apt-get` finishes, I can type commands and everything works normally.  I can't type commands while `apt-get` is running though.  I am using Ubuntu 12.04.  I guess I should report this as a bug.

Comment: I understand.  I entered the command quickly while it was still running, and when it finished several seconds later, it echoed the command and the result.  But I just did the update, and didn't actually install anything.

Comment: Did you add the `-y` switch OR confirm installation before entering the other command? Otherwise your input just goes to the prompt which comes up when trying to install larger packages.

Comment: @izx: I did not add `-y`, but it was a command that did not ask for input from its `stdin`.  For example, I just tried `sudo apt-get install pigz`, which did not ask for any confirmation, but it still behaved the way I describe in my question.  For completeness, I tried `sudo apt-get -y install pigz` with the same results.

Comment: @MartyFried: looks like there is something weird about my setup then.  I will try to find out what's happening.  Thanks!

Comment: Well, perhaps you should double-check using just the update, like I did, to see if that behaves differently for some reason.  It's possible that the install is checking the keyboard for something, and discarding unrecognized input.  You never know.  I always confirm even unlikely scenarios when debugging, and often find that what I thought was impossible was actually happening.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try to execute any command by adding in the very end of the command the `&`., e.g.: `dolphin &`. This way the process will run on the background and the terminal will be free to operate on.

Update: it seems, however, that interactive processes, like `sudo apt-get install <package>` that expect a user input (for example sudo's password) just wait in the background. They can be re-reached with the command `fg`.